# selecting items count in mysql

Tags: mysql, count, items

I've a table like the following,

id    ip                          rating
1      192.161.0.1    3
1      192.161.0.2    4
1      192.161.0.4    3
2      192.161.0.5    1

and i need the result somethin like,

id    rating    count
1       3                   2
1       4                   1
2       1                   1

is it possible in mysql?

Comment: Will records having the same `rating`, have the same `id` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GROUP BY` can be applied to multiple columns at once. Try:

```
SELECT id, rating, COUNT(id) AS count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id, rating
ORDER BY id, rating
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `id`, `rating`, COUNT(`id`) AS `count` FROM `table` GROUP BY `id`, `rating`.
```

You should normalise your table more.

Answer (score 1):

Query should be like this

```
SELECT id, rating, COUNT(rating) AS count
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY  id,rating
ORDER BY id, rating
```

Comment: Thanks harishphp,bolu and Tomalak Geret'kal for your quick response.All your queries worked well. seems simple query but scratching my head for hours... feels too bad!! any how thanks 4 all...